# Optimising Lucky Number Program

Tags: java, array

In this, we are given an array of numbers, say 1 2 3 4.

We start from a given position, let's say the 1st position.
We cancel that number and move forward that many non-cancelled numbers. The number on which we stop again has the same procedure.This is repeated until only one number is left. That is the lucky number.

**1** 2 3 4

**2** 3 4

3 **4**

**3**

My code:

```
import java.util.*;

class ln
{
    public static void main(String[] ar)throws Exception
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many nos. will you enter: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int[] a = new int[n];
        System.out.print("Enter the nos.: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("From which position do you want to start: ");
        int st = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++)
        {
            int j = a[st - 1];
            a[st - 1] = 0;
            int s = (int)Math.signum(j);
            while(j != 0)
            {
                if(a[st-1] != 0)
                    j -= s;
                st += s;
                if(st > a.length)
                    st = 1;
                else if(st < 1)
                    st = a.length;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            if(a[i] != 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Final no.: " + a[i]);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Please tell if there is a more elegant way of doing this .

Comment: Your current code doesn't work as you have described. The array `1 2 3 4` and the starting number `1` returns `2`, not `3` as you have described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a more elegant way of doing this. (That's all you wanted to know, isn't it?)

First of all, here's some general comments about your code:

- Your `Scanner` should be closed when you are done with it. `sc.close();`
- You use in total six different names for variables. All of these have a variable name of one or two single characters. It is hard to understand their purpose because of the short variable names you have given them. Possible better names could be `currentIndex`, `sign`, `currentNumber`...
- Use methods. A method should do one thing and it should do that one thing well. Your main method currently does:

  - Receive user input and put it into an array
  - Determine the "final number" according to your rules for this array
  - Display result to user

  At least make a separate method for determining the final number for an array. The method could be something like this: `public static int finalNumber(int[] inputArray)`

Use an if-statement to check if you are currently processing the last number. This will get rid of the last for-loop in your current code, which only loops through the array and shows the non-zero number it encounters.

There is some things that can be simplified within your algorithm as well.

- loop x number of times, where x equals array size
- get the value at the current index
- get the sign of the current value
- modify the current index by + current value
- while the value at the current index is zero, modify the current index by the value of sign

When modifying the index, you can use the modulo `%` operator to make sure that it is within the bounds of the array.

Here is what I would do:

```
public static int luckyNumber(int[] a, int index) {
    List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>(a.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        // Add the values to a list so that it is easy to remove them later
        ints.add(a[i]);
    }
    int lastValue = 0;
    while (!ints.isEmpty()) {
        // Save the index that should be removed later
        int oldIndex = index;
        int currentNumber = ints.get(index);
        index = index + currentNumber;

        // Make sure that the index is within a valid range
        if (index < 0)
            index += ints.size() * Math.abs(index);
        index = index % ints.size();

        // Remove the old index and adjust the index value if the index removed was before the current index.
        lastValue = ints.remove(oldIndex);
        if (oldIndex <= index) index--;
    }
    // Once the list is empty, return the last value that was removed
    return lastValue;
}
```

All these tests will print the lovely number 42:

```
System.out.println(luckyNumber(new int[]{ 1, 2, 42, 4 }, 0));
System.out.println(luckyNumber(new int[]{ 1, -1, 42, 4 }, 0));
System.out.println(luckyNumber(new int[]{ 1, -1, 2, 42, -4 }, 1));
```

Comment: "9 9 8 1" , starting with '0' gives error